# Converter string de código PDF em arraybuffer/blob para download do client

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, pdf, blob

Estou tendo problemas já a algum tempo, então decidi perguntar aqui, pois já estou sem opções.

Eu estou recebendo um pdf de uma api feita em java.
Eu recebo esse pdf pelo backend, em python, pois preciso passar um token de  autentiacação para consumir o serviço. Dito isso, recebo um código específico de pdf. Abaixo, meu request, e meu retorno.

```py
def get_relatorio(self, solicitacao, tokenAcesso):
    headers = {'Authorization' : 'Token ' + tokenAcesso, 'Accept' : 'application/pdf'}

    response = requests.get(self.uri + '/relatorios/solicitacao/' + solicitacao, headers=headers)

    return response.content
```

e meu retorno vem no seguinte formato:

```
%PDF-1.4
%
4 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/Height 
50/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Width 144/Length 
1325/BitsPerComponent 8>>stream
xLUeϽ{"pf8E\cE.D)0`WKڬ5eڐi"k@)v?ƺHZ.!=xZy<>ϹqqgO̊7(W@? 
$(wQY4gmqШt_?̍!!N9`9Fj  uUa+Ϥ`  eV%Wd'7}v!̙Ux<R_cZ{FDrx ]o?#}߯ 
pN!o/eSc4Eq?18MtK
```

[...]

Não vou postar o código todo por questão de ser um documento particular, mas creio já ser possível identificar de qual código se trata.

Buscar por `response.encoding` me trás 'utf-8'.

Eu preciso consumir esse código, e servir num `Blob` no front end com javascript.

Já busquei e achei a solução abaixo:

```js
   var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   window.open(fileURL);
```

Onde `data` seria o código do pdf. Só que fazendo isso me gera um pdf totalmente em branco, apesar de ter a quantidade de páginas correta. Pesquisei, e isso ocorre pois preciso passar o objeto `data` como um `arraybuffer` ao invés de uma string que é o que eu recebo do python, e a única forma que achei de fazer isso seria fazendo um ajax e setando o responseType para `arraybuffer`.
Eu pego esse código de dentro do template, entretanto, e não via ajax, e portanto não consigo, de nenhuma forma, converter a string em arraybuffer ou num Blob válido de forma nenhuma para servir para o cliente.

Poderiam me ajudar com isso? Estou a bastante tempo buscando e ainda não consegui uma solução.

Obs.: Estou usando Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, da seguinte maneira:

No arquivo python, devolver o retorno assim:

```
return bytearray(response.content)
```

e, na hora de consumir, ao invés de usar o fetch ou o ajax do jquery, fazer da forma arcaica:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', `${PORTAL_API_URL}/solicitacoes/${solicitacao}/imprimir`, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/pdf');
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status >= 200 || this.status <= 400) {
            resolve(this.response)
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
});
```

Ai, recebendo o retorno deste request, consigo jogar dentro do Blob e gerar o pdf correto.